# Animation loop issue with Bezier and snapping issue with linear

Tags: animation, rigging

So I have an idle animation of my skeleton 160 frames each rot/pos is 40 frames apart, and I am trying to get it to smoothly go between each set of frames and also loop smoothly. I have my first and last frames set to the same values, my start at 1 and my end at 159. Bezier is causing my animation to flow smoothly between my first and last frame, but causes it to pauses when it loops back from frame 159 to frame 1, while Linear causes it to loop perfectly from frame 159 to frame 1, but causes my frames in between the beginning and last frame to snap very quickly which makes it look jerky.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This can be effected in the Graph editor. Use Bezier throughout but at the end and start frames (160 & 1), swing those keyframe handles so that frame160 doesn't slow down and frame 1 kicks off without a pause.  i.e. remove the curvature at the last (160) and also at the starting frame (1).  Loop the animation through 1 to 159 as before.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by stringing keyframe handles, could you explain more or link me a video or another forum post if you know of one?

Answer (score 1):

Looping animation back to 1st frame - Smooth transition :

The gif animation is doing what you're seeking, using Bezier throughout, but straightening the curves in the graph editor at the first and last frames. (where it crosses the red line at the left)

[image]

How it's done -

Select the cube (moving object) and go to the Graph Editor.

In there select the first keyframe for the axis required (red is X, green is Y) and use the keyframe handles to straighten out the starting curve so the object kicks off in linear fashion, i.e. without accelleration.

[image]

Go to that same axis' last keyframe and do the same.

Ensure that the exit curve (at last keyframe) is at much the same angle as the first's.   That will ensure the object doesn't twitch, when the timeline cursor loops back to frame 1.

(in the example animation at top, that's where the thin cube crosses the red line at the left)

Do the same with the other axis'.  In this example the Z axis wasn't used.